# what is current mirror?

Tags: current, analog, current-source, current-mirror

I was looking for a high-level explanation about the current mirror but couldn't find it. Can someone explain what is current mirror using simple words? What does it do? and what is the real application that uses the current mirror?

Comment: what research have you done?  ... what did you not understand in the research results?

Comment: *a high-level explanation*: A current mirror mirrors or copies a current. There are plenty of explanations to be found if you just look for them. If these are too detailed for you then why do you care about the current mirror? A current mirror is a circuit that needs to be understood properly otherwise that knowledge is useless. You really need to spend more time studying and ask a more detailed (less general) question.

Comment: Copy paste this to Google. And go thru each link that popped up. A thousand tutorials. Finally come back with a specific doubt.